# How van I allow index only for same profile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app is a weight loss app. It uses Devise for user authentication.

A user `has_one :profile` (the profile table holds the `user_id` as foreign key) that stores data like prename, surname etc. and is created automatically when a user signs up. A profile `has_many :weights` (users of the app should weigh themselves regularly and store their new weight in this table). So far so good.

I have the following problem:
If a logged in user goes to the index page of the weight controller he sees only his own weights. However, if this user now changes the profile_id in the URL bar he can also see the weights of that other profile (although it is not "his" profile). Additionally, he can now create a new weight, which then holds the other profile_id (which is obviously not his own).

What I managed to do is to generally restrict users to edit or destroy weights which do not hold their own profile_id (through `before_action :require_same_weight_profile` in my weights_controller.rb).

My question now: how can I prevent this user (that has a certain profile) to do the stuff described above?

I'm sure the answer is pretty simple (I started coding just a few months ago).

> **UPDATE** In the meanwhile I found a solution. Unfortunately the suggested solutions in the comments did not work for me. What does
>   work is the following:
>
> **My update in weights_controller.rb**
>
> ```
> before_action :require_permission
>
> ...
>
> def require_permission
>   if current_user != Profile.find(params[:profile_id]).user
>     redirect_to root_path
>   end
> end
> ```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :profiles, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update] do
    resources :weights

  end
```

**profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :pal
  has_many :weights, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :goal
end
```

**weight.rb**

```
class Weight < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

**weights_controller.rb**

```
class WeightsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile
  before_action :load_profile
  before_action :set_weight, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :require_same_weight_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /weights
  # GET /weights.json
  def index
    @weights = Profile.find(params[:profile_id]).weights
  end

  # GET /weights/1
  # GET /weights/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /weights/new
  def new
    @weight = Weight.new(:profile_id => params[:profile_id])
  end

  # GET /weights/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /weights
  # POST /weights.json
  def create
    @weight = Weight.new(weight_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @weight.save
        format.html { redirect_to profile_weights_path, notice: 'Weight was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @weight }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @weight.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /weights/1
  # PATCH/PUT /weights/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @weight.update(weight_params)
        format.html { redirect_to profile_weights_path, notice: 'Weight was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @weight }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @weight.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /weights/1
  # DELETE /weights/1.json
  def destroy
    @weight.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profile_weights_path, notice: 'Weight was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_weight
      @weight = Weight.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find_by(user_id: params[:id])
    end

    def load_profile
      @profile = current_user.profile #|| current_user.build_profile
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def weight_params
      params.require(:weight).permit(:profile_id, :weight, :weight_day)
    end

    # This checks if the current user wants to deal with weights other than his own
    def require_same_weight_profile
      if @weight.profile_id != current_user.profile.id
        flash[:danger] = "You can only edit or delete your own weights"
        redirect_to profile_weights_path(current_user.profile)
      end
    end
end
```

**profiles_controller.rb**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :load_profile


  # GET /profiles
  # GET /profiles.json
  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
  end

  # GET /profiles/1
  # GET /profiles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /profiles/new
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  # GET /profiles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /profiles
  # POST /profiles.json
  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
    @profile.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /profiles/1
  # DELETE /profiles/1.json
  def destroy
    @profile.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profiles_url, notice: 'Profile was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find_by(user_id: params[:id])
    end

    def load_profile
      @profile = current_user.profile #|| current_user.build_profile
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def profile_params
      params.fetch(:profile, {}).permit(:prename, :surname, :birthdate, :gender, :size, :pal_id) 
    end

end
```

Comment: you have already done what is supposed to be done

Comment: @Oliver is there any reason weights are a nested resource under profiles?  You could remove the nesting and just fetch the current user's weights

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure the user is the owner of the page he's watching. That's a common security issue you must be aware in every app you make

```
def show
unless @weight.profile_id == current_user.id
redirect_to '/root'

end
```

If your profile is private (profiles/1) is just for user 1 to see you need to add that code as well to the profile controller.

Comment: are you kidding me? its a self explanatory code and i told why he should do that... what else am i supposed to say?

Comment: @Boltz0r looking at OP's code User and Profile aren't the same thing, so you need to check the weight's profile id against the current user's profile's id.

Comment: Thx a lot. Unfortuantely did not work for me. But found a different solution that works (update in the article).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a callback to verify ownership before you show the profile; if the profile doesn't belong to the current user, then return a 403 Forbidden.

The callback could look something like this:

```
def verify_ownership
  if @weight.profile.user != current_user
    render :status => 403 and return
  end
end
```

Add it to your callback chain using:

```
before_action :set_weight
before_action :verify_ownership
```

Make sure to call `set_weight` *before* this callback, so that the `@weight` variable isn't `nil`.

You can do something very similar for profiles themselves: simply change the callback to the following, and add it to the callback chain in the same way.

```
def verify_ownership
  if @profile.user != current_user
    render :status => 403 and return
  end
end
```

Comment: Thx a lot. Unfortuantely did not work for me. But found a different solution that works (update in the article).

Comment: FWIW, this isn't a callback, it's a filter.

Comment: Thx. I changed it to before_action.